# How to calculate with html form select and option in php

Tags: php, html, forms

A form that takes a lot of information from the user and processes it, and finally a number is displayed.
A number of objects are obtained according to other objects.

**index.php**

```
 <form action="calc.php" method="POST">
     <select name="NumberOfPeople2">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
     </select>
     <select name="NumberOfBathTimes">
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
      </select>
     <select name="DurationOfBathing">
        <option value="10">10 min</option>
        <option value="20">20 min</option>
      </select>
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

**calc.php**

```
<?php
 include 'include/calc.inc.php';

$NumberOfPeople = $_POST['NumberOfPeople'];

$NumberOfBathTimes = $_POST['NumberOfBathTimes'];

if($_POST['DurationOfBathing']=='10')
{
    $DurationOfBathing='60';
}
if($_POST['DurationOfBathing']=='20')
{
    $DurationOfBathing='100';
}
if($_POST['NumberOfBathTimes']=='1')
{
    $FactorUseBath='0.14285714';
    $FactorNumberBath='1.2';
}
if($_POST['NumberOfBathTimes']=='2')
{
    $FactorUseBath='0.28571429';
    $FactorNumberBath='1.2';
}



$ConsumptionBath = new Calc($NumberOfPeople,$DurationOfBathing,$FactorUseBath,$FactorNumberBath);
echo $ConsumptionBath->calcMethod();
```

**calc.inc.php**

```
<?php
class Calc{

public $NumberOfPeople;
public $DurationOfBathing;
public $FactorUseBath;
public $FactorNumberBath;

public function __construct($NumberOfPeople,$DurationOfBathing,$FactorUseBath,$FactorNumberBath){

        $this->NumberOfPeople = $NumberOfPeople;
        $this->DurationOfBathing; = $DurationOfBathing;
        $this->FactorUseBath; = $FactorUseBath;
        $this->FactorNumberBath; = $FactorNumberBath;
}
public function calcMethod(){
    $result = $this->DurationOfBathing*$this->FactorUseBath;*$this->FactorNumberBath*$this->NumberOfPeople;
    return $result;
}
 }
```

All objects obtained must be multiplied.
The answer is $ConsumptionBath
Is this the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is right way, but you should declare each and every variable somewhere which is used in script. For example, in your given script, variable `$DurationOfBathing` is initialised only in `if` conditions and will give `undefined variable` error in case `if` conditions fails. So I've updated code below:

```
include 'include/calc.inc.php';

$NumberOfPeople = $_POST['NumberOfPeople'];

$NumberOfBathTimes = $_POST['NumberOfBathTimes'];

$DurationOfBathing = $FactorUseBath = $FactorNumberBath = '';
if ($_POST['DurationOfBathing'] == '10') {
    $DurationOfBathing = '60';
} else if ($_POST['DurationOfBathing'] == '20') {
    $DurationOfBathing = '100';
}
if ($_POST['NumberOfBathTimes'] == '1') {
    $FactorUseBath = '0.14285714';
    $FactorNumberBath = '1.2';
} else if ($_POST['NumberOfBathTimes'] == '2') {
    $FactorUseBath = '0.28571429';
    $FactorNumberBath = '1.2';
}
$ConsumptionBath = new Calc($NumberOfPeople, $DurationOfBathing, $FactorUseBath, $FactorNumberBath);
echo $ConsumptionBath->calcMethod();
```

**Update**

There is some problem in class as well. Some extra semi colons `;` are added there. Use this updated code:

```
<?php

class Calc {

    public $NumberOfPeople;
    public $DurationOfBathing;
    public $FactorUseBath;
    public $FactorNumberBath;

    public function __construct($NumberOfPeople, $DurationOfBathing, $FactorUseBath, $FactorNumberBath) {

        $this->NumberOfPeople = $NumberOfPeople;
        $this->DurationOfBathing = $DurationOfBathing;
        $this->FactorUseBath = $FactorUseBath;
        $this->FactorNumberBath = $FactorNumberBath;
    }

    public function calcMethod() {
        $result = $this->DurationOfBathing * $this->FactorUseBath * $this->FactorNumberBath * $this->NumberOfPeople;
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now this is calcMethod (); Returns

Comment: I checked the lines, but when I submit, it shows the sentence: calcMethod ();

Comment: Answer Updated!

Comment: Oh no, again the same problem, the other parts of my code do not have a problem?

Comment: Please guide me about this topic.

Comment: What's the output its showing? I'm not getting what problem you are facing.

Comment: I've tried same program and its working fine as it should. Have you updated code that I've wrote above.